# Is the topology $\mathcal T = \{U \subseteq \mathbb Z \mid \forall n \in U, -n \in U\}$ on $\mathbb Z$ connected?

Tags: general-topology

> Is the topology $\mathcal T = \{U \subseteq \mathbb Z \mid U \text{ is symmetric}\}$ on $\mathbb Z$ connected?

A subset $U \subseteq \mathbb Z$ is *symmetric* iff for all $n \in U$, $-n \in U$.

I know that to prove that the topological space $(\mathbb Z, \mathcal T)$ is connected, we can show that $\mathbb Z$ has no separation. But for this one I do not know how. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric"?

Comment: Could you please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics? I'm reading this on my phone, and all I see are fourteen crossed-out boxes with some writing in-between.

Comment: I just edit my question.

Comment: I still see all the boxes, and I have no way of knowing whether they hide information that is relevant, or if they just say "U is symmetric" a second time.

Comment: @VuiTinh: there are two answers. Both solve your problem. You should accept one of them by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** The complement of a symmetric set is symmetric.

Comment: May I have more detail?

Comment: @Vui Tinh What is your definition of a connected space?

Comment: X is connected if it has no separation, therefore X is connected iff X = U u V implies U=X or U=empty set.

Comment: @ Servaes Here what I understand let U ∈ T then V= Z-U also ∈ T since complement of a symmetric set is symmetric. Then Z = U u V, U and V are disjoint, nonempty subset of Z then Z has a separation then Z is disconnected. Is it right?

Comment: @Vui Tinh I can't make anything of the math, all I see is boxes. Please use MathJax. But the gist of your argument seems right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ denote the set  of positive (edit: non-negative)  integers with discrete topology. Clearly P is a disconnected space. Define a function from your set to $P$ by $x\mapsto |x|$. Check that inverse image of any open set is open. This function is onto. Can you now see the answer to your question?

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:  Let me expand adding all the details. There is a general theorem that states that for continuous maps $f\colon X\to Y$ from one topological space $X$ to another $Y$, if $X$ is connected then $f(X)$ is also connected. (It is not difficult to prove, assume there is a separation for $Y$ take the inverse images and get one for $X$).

For the modulus function I have defined $\mathbf{Z}\to P$ inverse image of any set is symmetric, so it is continuous. But P being discrete (with more than one element) it  is disconnected. Modulus function is *onto* $P$. So if $\mathbf Z$ were connected then its image $P$ would also be connected. But  $P$ is not. So ....

Comment: @Brian M Scott: I edited to include the crucial missing 0. Thanks.

Comment: @ P Vanchinathan: I still do not see what you meant. Please tell more. Thnks

Comment: @VuiTinh: i have elaborated and expanded the answer. You should accept Servaes answer as it is direct, simple and  you seem to have understood.